# AED-SAR and SAR-AED currency Switching magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I have 4 currency (AED, USD, GBP, SAR) in my store AED is my base and i have 2 store (English and Arabic). All the currencies working properly but when i change AED to SAR or SAR to AED it's not working.

Comment: what you mean by not working? does it means not changing the price of the product?

Comment: Yes price and currency are not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link maybe you missed any steps

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-set-up-different-currencies-for-different-magento-2-store-views/

after that also make sure to define currency rates here(maybe your AED and SAR currency rates same)

> Store -> currency rate

try to clear cache

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I have already followed all steps and my other currencies are reflecting properly but only AED to SAR and SAR to AED conversion is not reflecting...

Comment: If i setup any new currency it's also working but SAR is not working.

Comment: in my case it's working fine, maybe any custom code may affect, did you tried in fresh setup?

Comment: All the currencies (Inc. AED to SAR - SAR to AED) are working fine on product detail page only but not working on a home page and category catalog page.

Comment: Could you tell me which custom code effect currency section?